# Show that $M_{x}(t) = \left(\frac{1}{1-{\beta} t}\right)^{\alpha}$

Tags: gamma-function

So I have been following through some notes on the gamma function to try and understand how this is done, and I am stuck at one step:

So I have that $M_{X}(t) = E\left(e^{tX}\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx}f_{X}(x)dx $,

where $f_{X}(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha - 1}e^{\frac{-x}{\beta}}}{\beta^{\alpha}\gamma(\alpha)} $

$ \gamma(\alpha)$, is the gamma function.

= $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx} \frac{x^{\alpha - 1}e^{\frac{-x}{\beta}}}{\beta^{\alpha}\gamma(\alpha)} dx $

= $\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\gamma(\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha -1}e^{-x\left(\frac{1}{\beta} - t\right)} dx   $

So the integral is finite if $\frac{1}{\beta} - t > 0$, Let $\frac{1}{\beta} - t = \frac{1}{\phi}$

= $\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\gamma(\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha -1}e^{\frac{-x}{\phi}} dx   $

Here is where I am unsure of how this jump is made:

= $\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\gamma(\alpha)} [\gamma(\alpha)\phi^{\alpha}]  $

The rest of the solution I am ok with, but how is this jump made from the 2nd to last step to this last step? Could someone explain the steps for me?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your exposition contains errors: (i) $f(x) dx$ is not "the gamma function". If I plug in 2, I don't get $\Gamma(2)$ coming out, for example; (ii) you have some mathematics beginning with "=". What's the LHS?  (iii) the last step is simply a matter of recognizing the density function.

Comment: You are correct, I made an error in posting the question, which I have now amended. I'm trying to learn how the jump from the 2nd last step to the last step is made - could you elaborate a little further?

Comment: What's the integral of a density function over the region where it's non-zero?

Comment: ... So, if you see something proportional to a density, mutiply and divide by the quantity required to make it a density, leaving a constant times something that integrates to a known (and very simple) value.

Answer (score 0):

Once you reached the identity
$$
M_X(t)=\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha -1}\mathrm e^{-x/\phi(t)} \mathrm dx,
$$
where $\phi(t)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}-t$, the change of variable $x=\phi(t) u$ yields 
$$
M_X(t)=\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}\phi(t)^{\alpha} \int_{0}^{\infty}u^{\alpha -1}\mathrm e^{-u} \mathrm du.
$$
One can identify the last integral without computing it since $M_X(0)=1$, hence
$$
M_X(t)=\phi(t)^{\alpha}\phi(0)^{-\alpha},
$$
and I am sure you can complete the proof.

Comment: The "gamma function" is $\Gamma$, not $\gamma$.

Comment: Is it the suggestion to complete the proof that is so outrageous that it provokes a downvote? Well, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Gamma density with parameters
(\alpha,\beta)
is given by
(\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x})
X has density
(\frac{1}{\theta}\textbf{1}_{{0\le X\le \theta}})
Hence posterior density is proportional to

(\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\frac{1}{\theta}\textbf{1}_{{0\le X\le \theta}})

Comment: Please, edit you post using MathJax. You forgot about dollar signs around your formulas.